# Dynamic dll loading from byte array with dependency management

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, dll

I'm trying to dynamicaly load some C# DLLs on a C# application. I got all the DLL in a `byte[]` list and I want to load them without writing them to dll file.

My application crashes when I want to use a dll application. 
It returns me a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` because it does not find the dll file.

I use `Assembly.Load()` on each `byte[]` dll and it seems to work properly (no crash and the Assembly List count for the  increase) and I load them in the good order (I don't know it it is necessary).

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(binDll);
AssemblyName[] referencedAssembly = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
foreach (AssemblyName referencedAssemblyName in referencedAssembly)
{
    if (!loadedDllList.Contains(referencedAssemblyName.Name) && this.Apps.Where(a => a.Item1 == referencedAssemblyName.Name).Count() > 0)
    {
        this.loadDll(referencedAssemblyName.Name);
    }
}

TX.AddInStore.Load(binDll, dllName, null, null); //LOAD DLL on our application
loadedDllList.Add(dllName);
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "when I want to use a dll application"? What is TX.AddInStore.Load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event and return the correct assemblies when the Common Language Runtime fails to resolve them by itself.

Assemblies can be loaded into one of several load contexts, or without context. The `Load(byte[])` method loads assemblies without context and one of many disadvantages is that other assemblies cannot bind to them automatically. Please, read [Best Practices for Assembly Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx) in MSDN for more information.